# How to declare an intent-filter for a Receiver class which is present in an external library.

Tags: android, android-manifest, broadcastreceiver

I've created a library one of whose class is

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{...}
```

Now since this class extends BroadcaseReceiver so I need to declare intent-filter like this:

```
<receiver android:name="SmsReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But, now since the SmsReceiver class is a part of external library so, if I declare the intent-filter like above in the application (application package is com.abc.test) where I'm using the SmsReceiver class, I get an error in the AndroidManifest.xml which says

```
Class com.abc.test.SmsReceiver doesn't exist
```

What I need to do to get it working? The library has been included in the project build path and I'm able to call the SmsReceiver class from the app (com.abc.test). The only problem is that the BroadcastReceiver (our SmsReciever class) won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `android:name="the.fully.qualified.class.name.SmsReceiver"`, where `the.fully.qualified.class.name.SmsReceiver` is the fully-qualified class name of the `SmsReceiver` class.