# isProviderEnabled always return true for network provider

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

Hi I am developing small android application in which I am trying to check whether network provider enabled or not. If not then look for GPS provider. But in my case for network provider always returns true.I tried to check that in following manner

```
    if (locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
getLastLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

} else if (locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, this);
getLastLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
```

In above code network provider always return true. Even I don't have any network provider. Is there anything wrong I am doing? Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: your dont have wifi either?

Comment: yeah I don't have wifi either as well in setting of wifi `scanning always available` also disabled.

Answer (score 3):

In order for Network Location to be disabled, you must either set your Location Mode to off, or GPS only.

So, for `isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)` to return false, it will either need to look like this (completely disabled):

[image]

Or this (Location enabled, GPS only):

[image]

To see what it looks like on KitKat, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30580898/4409409